# How to draw one thin and one thick line next to each other

Tags: header-footer, rules

How can we draw line depicted below in LaTeX?

[image]

That is, a thin line and thick line with gap of height of thin line in between? Can you please suggest recommended class for same?

Comment: So you want this as a header (and possibly a footer) rule?

Comment: This will be used as header rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like

```
\def\mydoublerule#1#2#3{%%
  \hrule width#1 height#2 \vskip#2
  \hrule width#1 height#3 
}
```

Where

```
#1 is the width or the rule
#2 is the height of the first rule
#3 is the height of the second rule
```

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\mydoublerule#1#2#3{%%
  \hrule width#1 height#2 \vskip#2
  \hrule width#1 height#3 
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\vspace{1ex}
\mydoublerule{\linewidth}{1pt}{3pt}
\vspace{1ex}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To use this as a rule in the head of each page, you can load `fancyhdr` and do something like

```
\renewcommand\headrule{%%
    \mydoublerlue{\linewidth}{1pt}{3pt}%%
    \vskip-\dimexpr1pt+3pt\relax}
```

Comment: @PawanMude I've modified my answer to better handle spacing above and below the rule.

Answer (score 6):

The following uses [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) which provides `\headrule` and can be easily changed. It's been updated to set a rule of width `1pt`, followed by a `1pt` gap, followed by a rule of with `2.5pt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2.5pt}
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
  \hrule\@height 1pt\@width\headwidth\vskip 1pt
  \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth \vskip\dimexpr-\headrulewidth-2pt\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Of course, change these rule widths to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Adjust the height 1pt and \kern 1pt with equal dimension
\newcommand{\sline}{%
    \hrule height 1pt width \hsize \kern 1pt \hrule width \hsize height 2pt%
    }
\begin{document}
\sline
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can choose values manually, the solution is very simple:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt} % A
\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip1.2pt % A+B
\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt} %B

\end{document}
```